# Dynamically set sql-default value with table-name in SQLModel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlmodel

I'm trying to create a base-class in SQLModel which looks like this:

```py
class BaseModel(SQLModel):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__

    guid: Optional[UUID] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

class SequencedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    sequence_id: str = Field(sa_column=Column(VARCHAR(50), server_default=text(f"SELECT '{TABLENAME}_' + convert(varchar(10), NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.sequence)")))
```

so I got a table like this:

```py
class Project(SequencedBaseModel):
    ...
```

where alembic would generate a migration for a table `Project` with columns `guid` and `sequence_id`. The default-value for sequence-id is a sequence which is generated with

```sql
SELECT '{TABLENAME}_' + convert(varchar(10), NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.sequence)
```

and should insert into project-table the values `Project_1`, `Project_2`, `...`

Any idea on how to set the tablename dynamically? I cannot use a constructor for setting the columns because alembic is ignoring them, I cannot access the `__tablename__()` function, or `cls`, because the columns are static...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you have an attribute that relies on a `@declared_attr`, it must also be a `@declared_attr`, since SqlAlchemy will wait until the whole mapping is completed and the classes get actual tables to be resolved (at least, that is my understanding). Now: `declared_attr`(s) are an SqlAlchemy concept, whereas the idea of `Field` is an SQLModel concept and they don't seem to talk to each other regarding this sort of *"""deferred"""* attribute thingy (*"""deferred"""* in the sense that it won't be evaluated until the mapping is completed and the tables known, not [deferred](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.deferred) as in waiting until it's accessed)... at least, not that I know.

You *could* (maybe? hopefully?) do something like what's recommended in [this SQLModel GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/240): *"""Defer"""* the SqlAlchemy Column and alias the SQLModel field:

```
class SequencedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    sequence_id: str = Field(alias="sequence_id")

    @declared_attr
    def sequence_id(cls):
        return Column(
            'sequence_id',
            VARCHAR(50),
            server_default=text(f"SELECT '{cls.__tablename__}_'"
                                f" + convert(varchar(10), NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.sequence)"))


class Project(SequencedBaseModel, table=True):
    pass
```

Running `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "init"` will produce a migration file with the proper `__tablename__ + '_'` (meaning: `Product_`) expanded in the `server_default`'s `SELECT...`:

```
def upgrade() -> None:
    op.create_table('Project',
    sa.Column('guid', sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.GUID(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('sequence_id', sa.VARCHAR(length=50), server_default=sa.text("SELECT 'Project_' + convert(varchar(10), NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.sequence)"), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('guid'),
    # ... 
    # ...
```

This assumes your alembic environment has been properly configured. I can't help but pointing out that alembic will generate the migration using `sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.GUID()` as the column type for the `guid` attribute, so you'll need to make sure the package `sqlmodel` is imported on each migration file. Probably by editing the template `script.py.mako` as described [in this link](https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-sqlmodel/) where it shows that you must add `import sqlmodel             # NEW` .

⚠️ I tried to test this, but I don't exactly know where `dbo.sequence` comes from (a SQL server, maybe?). I used a [PostgreSQL sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) (which I christened `so75719072`) to simulate it. This means that I can't confirm whether the syntax for the `DEFAULT SELECT...` will be valid in your situation. I'm quite suspicious about you being able to use the result of a `SELECT` as default value for a column but hopefully I'm wrong.

```
import uuid
from typing import Optional
from uuid import UUID

from sqlalchemy import Column, VARCHAR, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import declared_attr
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, create_engine, Session, select


class BaseModel(SQLModel):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'SO-75719072'}

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__

    guid: Optional[UUID] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)


class SequencedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    sequence_id: str = Field(alias="sequence_id")

    @declared_attr
    def sequence_id(cls):
        return Column(
            'sequence_id',
            VARCHAR(50),
            server_default=text(f"nextval('so75719072')"))


class Project(SequencedBaseModel, table=True):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine(
        "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgrespw@localhost:32768/stackoverflow")

    with Session(engine) as session:
        for i in range(3):
            proj1 = Project(guid=uuid.uuid4())
            session.add(proj1)
            session.commit()

    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Project).where(Project.sequence_id.in_(["1", "2", "3"]))
        for project in session.exec(statement):
            print(f"guid: {project.guid}")
```

Produces the following output:

```
guid: c5e5902d-e224-48f1-95f5-fa47a73f7b05
guid: 1c25550b-258c-49c5-9acc-90ae7ad8460c
guid: eb84e90c-9449-4974-8eb4-bad98728b0f9
```

Which came from the following table in Postgres:

```
# select * from "SO-75719072"."Project";
                 guid                 | sequence_id
--------------------------------------+-------------
 c5e5902d-e224-48f1-95f5-fa47a73f7b05 | 1
 1c25550b-258c-49c5-9acc-90ae7ad8460c | 2
 eb84e90c-9449-4974-8eb4-bad98728b0f9 | 3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: smooth... :) works like a charm. Thanks so much for this detailed explanation - bounty was worth it. (And `dbo.sequence` is just a sequence I created on sql server.)

Comment: Great! Glad I helped! And this was the first time I answered a bountied question as well, so, thank you.